# Chrome Long URL in Table Issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-tables

So I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure this issue out with Chrome and how it has a hard time wrapping long URLs in a table cell. I have seen a lot of questions regarding word wrapping and some even had with long URLs but none of them worked for me. So essentially, I tried putting in the td

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

but this doesn't wrap the long URL which is (changed here, doesn't go to anything):

```
https://differentName/api/?REQUEST=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%271.0%27%20%3F%3E%3Cnta%3E%3Capi%20version%3D%271.0%27%3E%woot%20function%3D%22login%22%3E%3Clogin%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bjpublic%something.com%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Flogin%3E%3Cpassword%3E%3C!%5BCDATA%5Bnta46550%5D%5D%3E%3C%2F
```

I've tried adding a width property onto the td but I get nothing. I was also told that when using the word-wrap property to also include:

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

But I don't want my columns fixed in width. Also, I don't have the wrapping issue if I use the fixed property. I'm working off of the latest version of Chrome (as of this date). No issues with FF 26.0 or IE 11. Any help would be great.

Comment: I'd love to take a look. Got a fiddle? I'm sure we just need some pseudo CSS magic.

Comment: I'm sorry it took me so long to get back with you. The fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qqsj8/. You can see how it goes out of the tabbed area, thats because of the last rows description that I was talking about. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Answered with `fiddle`. Let me know if that'll work for ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I would just establish a `class` on the `td` that you are having the issue with.**

In its current state, you are only `break`ing when spaces are present.

If you want to force breaks without spaces in Chrome as well, you can use the `CSS` `word-break: break-all;`

**Does something like this work for you?**

- http://jsfiddle.net/qqsj8/2/

**CSS:**

```
td.break {
    /* Be VERY careful with this, breaks normal words wh_erever */
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<td class="break">Why do...</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Although it does work, and it is actually what I have had in place for this, that section (Description) is generated from the code behind. These rows are records that are created using a repeater and pulled from a DB. So if it was static this wouldn't be an issue, but since the results are variable this won't work. Sorry, I should have given you more info on that.

Comment: You can't program a back-end service like `PHP` or `JAVA` to implement a class based on line breaks? C'mon man, I answered your question. Considering I was the only one, you should happily accept this as answered with the green checkbox next to the voting arrows and ask another question, especially considering this is relatively dead. You didn't even tag a single `back-end` protocol.

Comment: I feel like there is a CSS solution to this that I'm not seeing. Since I already had this pseudo solution in place, it unfortunately didn't answer my question. I'll leave this open for a little while before I close it and give credit (to you, unless a better answer comes along), since you didn't have all the info. Thank you for your help.